# How to perform a series of searches but skip a search if value is blank, in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I would like to search various columns in my sheet to find matches to certain cells. The issue comes from some of these cells may be blank and as they are I would like to skip it and do the next search. In the end I want it to mark "found here" against the rows that match all the value cells that have been filled in. My script so far is

```
function onSearch() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main Sheet");
    var searchVal1 = sheet.getRange("AE31").getValue();
    var searchVal2 = sheet.getRange("AE32").getValue();
    var searchVal3 = sheet.getRange("AE33").getValue();
    var searchCol1 = sheet.getRange(2,6,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var searchCol2 = sheet.getRange(2,7,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();    
    var searchCol3 = sheet.getRange(2,7,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); 
    for (var i = 0, len = searchCol1.length; i < len; i++) 
    for (var i = 0, len = searchCol2.length; i < len; i++)

{if (searchVal1 === "")
      (searchCol2[i][0] == searchVal2)
       else if (searchCol1[i][0] == searchVal1)
{if (searchCol2[i][0] == searchVal2)
    {if (searchVal2 === "")
      (searchCol3[i][0] == searchVal3)
       else if (searchCol2[i][0] == searchVal2)
{if (searchVal3 === "")
      else if (searchCol3[i][0] == searchVal3) 

{sheet.getRange(i + 2, 30).setValue("found here")
```

This does search and find the correct rows if all the values are in the cells (AE31,AE32,AE33) but if I take one out it produces no result.
[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CAflyzAIyb5Fuz3Ef2sLbhfFO9DXSNIVIh0h7uBEFQo/edit?usp=sharing) is an example of the data set I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Why are `searchCol2` and `searchCol3` identical?

You have this:

```
for (var i = 0, len = searchCol1.length; i < len; i++) 
for (var i = 0, len = searchCol2.length; i < len; i++)
```

Which is bad. If you want to nest `for` loop, use two different counter variables, typically `i` and `j` (and `k`)

You need to learn to properly indent your code. A good-looking code is easier to debug. Use [code beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) if you need help.

Code like `getRange("AE31")` will make code maintenance harder. Consider name your search term cell and use [`getRangeByName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRangeByName(String)) instead.

Here is the cleaned-up (and working) code:

```
function onSearch() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main Sheet");
  var searchVal1 = sheet.getRange("AE31").getValue();
  var searchVal2 = sheet.getRange("AE32").getValue();
  var searchVal3 = sheet.getRange("AE33").getValue();
  var searchCol1 = sheet.getRange(2, 6, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); // F2:F (address)
  var searchCol2 = sheet.getRange(2, 7, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); // G2:G (MIS)
  var searchCol3 = sheet.getRange(2, 7, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < searchCol1.length; i++) {
    if (
      ((searchVal1 == "") || (searchCol1[i][0] == searchVal1)) &&
      ((searchVal2 == "") || (searchCol2[i][0] == searchVal2)) &&
      ((searchVal3 == "") || (searchCol3[i][0] == searchVal3))
    ) {
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 30).setValue("found here")
    }
  }
}
```

The variable naming is confusing. I'd suggest `searchTerm` or `searchTermAddress` instead of `searchVal1`, and `searchRange` instead of `searchCol`